# Get textColor attr from what was defined in xml

Tags: android, xml, attributes, textview

I am trying to get the android:textColor that was set inside the xml layout in my CustomTextView.
How can I get it from the `AttributeSet attrs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```java
final String androidNamespace = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
String textColor = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidNamespace, "textColor");
```